# iOS How to delete added card from braintree

Tags: ios, xcode, braintree

I am using braintree ios sdk for my iPhone app.
It is working fine.
I have a doubt that we can delete added(credit/debit) card from braintree.
any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do it from the iOS SDK, do this on your backend using [their web libraries](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/delete/ruby).